# The file "assets/background.png" set as the parameter "image" was not found. pub finished with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen using flutter_native_splash 1.3.1 package. I created a folder called 'assets' in the lib folder and added that image to that folder. But I am getting the error mentioned in the question when I ran '`flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`' in the command line.

I added the following lines in pubspec.yaml as suggested by the package documentation.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#000000"
  image: assets/background.png
```

Can someone please explain what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you also added the image to your `assets` at `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: @esentis When I tried to add it there I got the following error 'The asset file 'images/background.png' doesn't exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.

Comment: Are you sure the folder is `images` and not just `assets/background.png` ?

Comment: @esentis  I tried both ways, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing the [Ehtesham Siddiquie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8345076/ehtesham-siddiquie) answer.
I think the assets folder should be at the root of the project (at the same level of pubspec.yaml and flutter_native_splash.yaml). but u created it in the lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps

1. Add flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.1 in pubspec.yaml
2. Create flutter_native_splash.yaml in root of project at same level as pubspec.yaml
3. Add below content in the above file

flutter_native_splash:

```
color: "#000000"
image: assets/background.png
```

4. Run this command in terminal

flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create

5. With above steps, splash screen will load properly but the error you mentioned might come. To remove that error enable below section in pubspec.yaml

assets:

```
- assets/background.png
```

6.Make sure you have assets directory in the root of project and background.png is present inside it.

7.Clean and build. it should work without any issues

Comment: let me know if the above solution solves your issue